# Firebase Console & SDK: Neither be able to create collection via console nor SDK

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I've tried to use Firebase Firestore in my latest NextJS project. As I tried to create a collection via the Firebase console the "save" button is always greyed out, even if I fill out the necessary information. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hLAi.png)

I took a look into the developer console of Chrome and noticed that Firebase itself threw many errors. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGyoA.png)
Many CORS errors but then there is this error:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.8.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

I also tried to add a document via the Firebase SDK. I used version **^9.6.7**.

My code looks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const app = initializeApp({
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "...",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
      messagingSenderId: "...",
      appId: "..."
    });

    setDoc(doc(getFirestore(), 'cities', 'LA'), {
      name: 'Los Angeles'
    })
      .then(_ => { console.log('inserted') });
  }, []);
```

But the only result I get is that the SDK starts a request which is pending about 40sec and then returns a 200. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikqXm.png)

After that the next request is triggered which results in the same behavior as the first one. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjcOk.png)

But the provided data isn't inserted into Firestore.

I didn't found any solution for this yet. Maybe you be able to help me with that.

Thanks.

Comment: facing the same issue, do you have found a solution ?

Comment: @Wawa unfortunately no

Comment: maybe try to use firebase/firestore/lite, it worked in some case for me, it's using HTTP requests instead HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The problem was apparently related to a VPN that I had installed. Once I removed the VPN software it started working again. For those who are curious and maybe have the same problem, I used NordVPN as the VPN software.